# Why the CascadeType.ALL isn't working anymore?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, generics

The code was refactored to use a generic class. It was expected that it should work correctly.

Before

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<Foo> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
    private Bar bar;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "foo__type", joinColumns = 
                    {@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = true)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = true)})
    private List<Type> types;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FooCell> cells;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "sort_order", nullable = false)
    private int sortOrder;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "manual_value")
    private String manualValue;

    @Transient
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean freeText;

    @Transient
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TreeNode typesTree = new DefaultTreeNode();

    @Transient
    @Getter
    private TreeNode[] selectedTypes;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "last_modification_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime lastModificationDate;
    
    public String getTypeNames() {
        Stream<String> fixedTypeNames = types == null ? Stream.empty() : types.stream().map(p -> p.getName());
        return fixedTypeNames.sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
    
    public String getCellValue(int sortOrder) {
        FooCell fooCell = getCell(sortOrder);
        return fooCell.getValue();
    }
 
    public FooCell getCell(int sortOrder) {
        return cells.stream().filter(cell -> cell.getArea().getSortOrder() == sortOrder).findFirst().get();
    }

    public void setSelectedTypes(TreeNode[] selectedTypes) {
        this.selectedTypes = selectedTypes;
        if (this.selectedTypes != null) {
            List<Type> typesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TreeNode node : this.selectedTypes) {
                if (node != null && node.getData() instanceof Type) {
                    typesList.add((Type) node.getData());
                }
            }
            this.setTypes(typesList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.sortOrder, o.getSortOrder());
    }
}
```

After the refactor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@AssociationOverride(
                name="footerOptions",
                joinTable=@JoinTable(
                                name = "foo_type", joinColumns =
                                {@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = true)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = true)}
                )
)
public class Foo extends CustomFooter<Type, FooCell, Foo> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
    private Bar bar;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Override
    public List<FooCell> getCells() {
        return super.getCells();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCells(List<FooCell> cells) {
        super.setCells(cells);
    }

    public String getTypeNames() {
        List<Type> types = getFooterOptions();
        Stream<String> fixedTypeNames = types == null ? Stream.empty() : types.stream().map(p -> p.getName());
        return fixedTypeNames.sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }

    public String getCellValue(int sortOrder) {
        FooCell fooCell = getCell(sortOrder);
        return fooCell.getValue();
    }

    public FooCell getCell(int sortOrder) {
        return getCells().stream().filter(cell -> cell.getArea().getSortOrder() == sortOrder).findFirst().get();
    }

    public void setSelectedTypes(TreeNode[] selectedTypes) {
        setSelectedItems(selectedTypes);
        if (getSelectedItems() != null) {
            List<Type> typesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TreeNode node : getSelectedItems()) {
                if (node != null && node.getData() instanceof Type) {
                    typesList.add((Type) node.getData());
                }
            }
            setFooterOptions(typesList);
        }
    }

}
```

CustomFooter.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class CustomFooter<FooterOptions, CellType, FooterType> extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany
    List<FooterOptions> footerOptions;

    @OneToMany
    List<CellType> cells;

    @Column(name = "sort_order", nullable = false)
    private int sortOrder;

    @Column(name = "manual_value")
    private String manualValue;

    @Transient
    boolean isFreeText;

    @Transient
    TreeNode items = new DefaultTreeNode();
    @Transient
    TreeNode[] selectedItems;

    @Column(name = "last_modification_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime lastModificationDate;

    public CustomFooter() {
    }

    public int compareTo(CustomFooter<FooterOptions, CellType, FooterType> o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.sortOrder, o.getSortOrder());
    }
}
```

**There's no change in the Bar entity**:

Bar entity

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<>();
```

The code set a list of Foo in Bar entity and when try to save it throws:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
> transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
> com.my.company.entity.FooCell

Or when try to load the Bar entity:

> Table 'db.foo_foo_cell' doesn't exist

What's the mistake in the code?

Comment: You cannot remap cells as you are in both CustomFooter and Foo. Have it in one and map it fully in that class.